# Discord.py spellcheck commands

Tags: python, discord.py

Recently, I looked up Stack Overflow and found this code which can check for potential typos:

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher
SequenceMatcher(None, "help", "hepl").ratio()
# Returns 0.75
```

This works for code **inside** the bot command. However, how should I make it so, if I make a typo in the command name, it will correct it and execute the command?

Comment: You mean if you do not know the first argument ('help')? I think you would need a list of available commands, and then compare your input to each one of the commands and decide for the highest SequenceMatcher.ratio.

Comment: I have a list of them, but how do I make it execute a different command than the one with a typo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if not isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        return

    message = ctx.message  # later overwrite the attributes

    used_prefix = ctx.prefix  # the prefix used
    used_command = message.content.split()[0][len(used_prefix):]  # getting the command, `!foo a b c` -> `foo`

    available_commands = [cmd.name for cmd in bot.commands]
    matches = {  # command name: ratio
        cmd: SequenceMatcher(None, cmd, used_command).ratio()
        for cmd in available_commands
    }

    command = max(matches.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])[0]  # the most similar command

    try:
        arguments = message.content.split(" ", 1)[1]
    except IndexError:
        arguments = ""  # command didn't take any arguments

    new_content = f"{used_prefix}{command} {arguments}".strip()
    message.content = new_content  # overwriting the "original" message

    await bot.process_commands(message)  # processing commands with the new, updated message
```