# How make a typo message?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to add a similar commands suggestion when the user make a typo.

Example: Right command: clear // User input: Cler // Bot response: Did you mean 'clear'?

I'm heard about `difflib.get_close_matches` and  I'm be able to make this works in a .py script but not with discord.py

Comment: Can you include the .py script in which you're able to make it work in the code?

Comment: And also the discord.py script that isn't working. So we can see what's wrong.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68624572/discord-py-spellcheck-commands

Answer (score 0):

You wanna have a list of all your bot commands.
Then you test with the on command error event if the command wasnt found. If it wasnt test for similar commands (Levenshtein distance: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance). Then send the user a message with the expected command if similar commands are found. Here is an example of how I would do it):

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from difflib import SequenceMatcher

BOT_PREFIX = '!'
bot = discord.Client(intents=discord.Intents.all(), status=discord.Status.dnd)
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix=BOT_PREFIX)
bot_commands = [] # all cmd names

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    global bot_commands
    bot_commands = [cmd.name for cmd in bot.commands]

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author.id == bot.user.id:
        return
    await bot.process_commands(message)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error): #catch error
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound):
        for i in bot_commands: #Looking for close matches in commands
            if float(SequenceMatcher(a=str(ctx.message.content).replace(BOT_PREFIX, '').lower(), b=i.lower()).ratio()) > float(0.67): #You can adjust the second float
                await ctx.send(f'Did you mean {i}?') #Your message
                break #Ignore similiar matches
    #raise error (optional)

bot.run('token')
```

Comment: Keep in mind that if your bot's command prefix is common enough, chances are that the user was actually trying to use some other bot in the same server/guild. Because of this, you should set the threshold (the value on the right-hand side of the `if`) reasonably high, so that it only triggers on words that you're sure are typos, not just commands you don't know.